# How can you get a list of IPs accessed by a defined Process?

Tags: windows, powershell

The goal of this is to redirect the traffic from a specific application *(The process name matching a specific Text)* to a separate gateway address without interfering with other traffic going through my main gateway, since there are network shares and other servers connected that cannot lose the connection. I have already been able to redirect specific IPs that I found in the Resource Manager, but they constantly change and sometimes parts of Programs access different servers which I cannot see until they are used, obviously.

The desired end result would be a list of IP addresses that the given Process is using. On this list I want to run a loop which basically routs the IP addresses to the other gateway:
`route add IP mask 255.255.255.255 otherGateway`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SysInternals TCPVcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) (TCPView for console) can do that. It has a command line option to output the result as CSV.

```
tcpvcon [-a] [-c] [-n] [process name or PID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proxy setting in app. If there is nonthing about proxy, try using [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/) or similar software.

Alternatively you can use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to get all connections made by process.
But beware of

- network calls can be made by child processes (ex., app.exe starts powershell that makes request)
- IP addresses can change due to many reasons.